# RewriteRule doesn´t work with language (404)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, qtranslate

I´m searching since two days to find a solution but don´t find a solution!
I add just two to show the problem because I alway get a 404...
Would be great if anybody can help me with this problem.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^seefracht-spedition\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/seefracht-spedition/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^luftfracht-spedition\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/luftfracht-spedition/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^service-zollabwicklung\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/service-zollabwicklung/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^lager-logistik\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/lager-logistik/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^service-hafenabwicklung\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/service-hafenabwicklung/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^umzug-spedition\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/umzug-spedition/  [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^kontakt-sats\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/kontakt-sats/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^standorte-sats\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/standorte-sats/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^downloads\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/downloads/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^impressum\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/impressum/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^news.php http://www.sats-logistics.com/news/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^links\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/links/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^daten/speditionsauftrag-luftfracht.pdf http://www.sats-logistics.com/download/speditionsauftrag-luftfracht.pdf [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
AddHandler x-mapp-php5  .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This URL I wan´t to add too:

```
RewriteRule ^en/index\.php http://www.sats-logistics.com/en/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^en/ocean-freight\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/en/ocean-freight/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^en/air-freight\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/en/air-freight/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^en/custom-brokerage\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/en/custom-brokerage/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^en/warehouse-logistics\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.comen/warehouse-logistics/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^en/port-handling\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/en/port-handling/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^en/moving-relocation\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/en/moving-relocation/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^en/contact\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/en/contact/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^en/locations\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/en/locations/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^en/downloads\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/en/downloads/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

> `I´m searching since two days to find a solution`

**You should have come to Stackoverflow earlier :P**

Change order of your rules and remove starting slash:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^luftfracht-spedition\.htm$ http://www.sats-logistics.com/luftfracht-spedition [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^en/custom-brokerage\.htm$ http://www.sats-logistics.com/en/custom-brokerage [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT FOR YOU FAST HELP!!!!!!!!

First RewriteRule is now working but the second doesn´t work...

This is the code I add:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^luftfracht-spedition.htm$ http://www.sats-logistics.com/luftfracht-spedition [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^en/custom-brokerage.htm$ http://www.sats-logistics.com/en/custom-brokerage [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: Actually that is also working, I just entered `http://www.sats-logistics.com/en/custom-brokerage.htm` and it became `http://www.sats-logistics.com/custom-brokerage/` in my browser.

Comment: Thats the problem! It should redirect to http://www.sats-logistics.com/en/custom-brokerage/ to see the site in english. Now I have english URL but German content.

Comment: All redirects exept the sites with another language (/en/) are working now fine! :-) Would be fine if you have a solution for the other problem!

Comment: Is there a .htaccess inside `/en/` folder also?

Comment: Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: Think this is the only one but let me check. .htaccess is located in the main file. This is the whole code:

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^seefracht-spedition\.htm http://www.sats-logistics.com/seefracht-spedition/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
AddHandler x-mapp-php5  .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: If you have a email address I could send you the whole code because some site won´t work. If possible I would pay for your service!

Comment: My email id is `anubhava[AT]aol[DOT]com` but I believe we're close to the solution. Just provide all the info by editing your question since its difficult to read from comments.

Comment: Because I´m new here I can´t add a new question here! -.-

Comment: No you can edit your own question by clicking o edit link just below your question.

Comment: Ok, send it twice! :-)

Comment: The .htaccess you've posted is this located in DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: In DOCUMENT_ROOT? :-) Its in the folder where the whole site is located. Add all other rules!

Comment: Add all of your new 301 rules on top just after `RewriteBase /` line.

Comment: Now I have following problem: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: comment out `#RewriteRule ^en/index\.php` rule and make sure to place `$` in the end as I showed in my answer.

Comment: So should I add this (#RewriteRule ^en/index\.php)?
Because currently it isn´t there!
Sorry but first time that I try to change .htaccess...

Comment: Avoid this rule for now and let's make everything else working first.

Comment: Won´t work... Don´t know whats going on! Sometimes it works and sometimes I get the 500

Comment: Since you're using 301 all the way. Make sure to test in a new browser.

Comment: Did you receive my email? Could you check on a testing site?

Comment: Just replied back by email to you.